# Phpmyadmin gibberish at main table overview (but ok when click on edit)

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, phpmyadmin

[image: phpmyadmin screenshot]

My phpmyadmin is funny

The last couple of days, the overview of the table columns is total "encoded" gibberish

**But when I click on edit on any of them, the real content shows just fine**
Everything is set to be UTF-8 by the way

The database works perfectly otherwise

Don't know what's happening. Do you?

Comment: What is the character set in your database and what is there in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: Connection Charset is UTF-8 bin. Charset for the database and all tables in is UTF-8 bin.

Comment: Can you please mention which phpMyAdmin version it is and are those fields of type binary or blob?

Comment: The fields are int and varchar. Phpmyadmin 3.3.0 (I cant't upgrade)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `$cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = true;` in **config.inc.php** and if it is `true` set it to `false`. That might help.

Answer (score 3):

With no version mentioned it's difficult to answer but it seems like those fields are of BINARY or BLOB data types or maybe because of utf8_bin they are treated as binary and are displayed in hexadecimal (0-9,A-F) form. Try this:

- Click on '+options' link (just above that display table)
- Uncheck 'Show binary contents as HEX' option.
- Click 'Go'.

**Edit 1 (In danish it should be something like this):**

- '+options' is '**+indstillinger**'
- 'Show binary contents as HEX' is '**Vis binært indhold som HEX**'
- 'Go' is '**Udfør**'

Comment: The fields are int and varchar. Phpmyadmin 3.3.0. Strange, they only look scewed at front table view, not in edit page

Comment: Can't see any options link

Comment: @mowgli, see translations in updated answer or try it by setting english language.

Comment: I have no binary/hex options